# Maintain tab position on refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, tabs

I'm having trouble solving a problem.

I work on MVC 4, and on my page I have a tab. When I refresh the page I can't keep the tab in the same position as it was before the refresh. I've been looking for a solution to keep the tab in the same position after I refresh it. The command I've tried for the refresh is `location.reload(true);`.

I have the the feeling I'm assigning the old tab position when the browser is still refreshing so my assignment is resetting from the refresh and the tab back at the default position.

I tried to call a Controller to do the assignment after the refresh with a wait function, but by doing so I stop the refresh too, so i do the assignment, the refresh goes on and my assignment is covered once again. I tried with a controller to do the `View()` to refresh the page without using the java command and then assign the tab in the right position, but the View doesn't refresh my page.

What can I do? What am I doing wrong? Can I use another command on JS or JQuery? Can i use another command and no View()?

I hope somebody can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage):

```
// Set current tab
localStorage.setItem("activeTab", 1); // 1 for tab index

// Retrieve active tab after reload
var activeTab = localStorage.getItem("activeTab"); // activeTab will be "1"
```

`localStorage` stores data between browser sessions, like if you close the browser, the data is kept. Use [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) to clear the data if browser/tab is closed.

This is a pure javascript solution.

[Here is a working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/0416uq3u/).

Comment: It doesn't work. Is there a way to do the assignment of the Tab only when the refresh is over? I mean waiting the end of the refresh?

Comment: @Marchin I have added a demo in the answer. Check it out how it works.

Comment: It still doesn't work, i use bootstrap and i did $('#atabM').tab('show'); and it places me in the right position, but the load still goes on and the tab is moved to the default position.

Comment: @Marchin it is always a good practice to add all frameworks and libraries you're using in your question. I did a demo in jQuery UI as an example. Anyway, as you're not using an *index* to open your tab, just store the tab id in the localStorage, then you use it on load event like: `$("#" + localStorage.getItem("tabId")).tab('show')`.